# All pushed back values in vector changing to default value

Tags: c++, vector

In an effort to reduce multiple functions (that were nearly identical) in my code, I decided to consolidate them all into one function which takes an additional parameter (a class with multiple parameters, actually), and then uses those values to imitate what the multiple functions would have done. Then, long story short, I put each of those class declarations into a vector, and now my program seems dysfunctional.

My multiple instances of a class:

```
FragmentCostParameters commonFCP = FragmentCostParameters(.05, 0);
FragmentCostParameters rareFCP = FragmentCostParameters(.05, 50);
FragmentCostParameters uniqueFCP = FragmentCostParameters(.05, 125);
FragmentCostParameters legendaryFCP = FragmentCostParameters(.02, 175);
FragmentCostParameters crystallineFCP = FragmentCostParameters(.02, 250);
FragmentCostParameters superEliteFCP = FragmentCostParameters(.02, 300);
```

Which get placed into a vector by:

```
vector<FragmentCostParameters> FCPs(6);

FCPs.push_back(FragmentCostParameters(.05, 0));
FCPs.push_back(FragmentCostParameters(.05, 50));
FCPs.push_back(FragmentCostParameters(.05, 125));
FCPs.push_back(FragmentCostParameters(.02, 175));
FCPs.push_back(FragmentCostParameters(.02, 250));
FCPs.push_back(FragmentCostParameters(.02, 300));
```

Additionally, that class is defined below:

```
class FragmentCostParameters {
public:
    double multFactor;
    double subtractFactor;
    FragmentCostParameters(double _multFactor, double _subtractFactor){
        multFactor = _multFactor;
        subtractFactor = _subtractFactor;
    }
    FragmentCostParameters(){
        multFactor = .05;
        subtractFactor = 0;
    }

};
```

Now, you'll notice that the default constructor for the `FragmentCostParameters` involves setting `multFactor = .05` and `subtractFactor = 0`. However, it seems that no matter what I push back, each of the values in my vector become mutated into those values. At least, that's what VS 2011 tells me the values are equal to when I'm looking at them in a local scope in the following function (which is the only place they're used).

```
int FragmentCost(double skillLevel, int duration, FragmentCostParameters FCP){
    return max((int)(ceil(FCP.multFactor*(skillLevel-FCP.subtractFactor))*ceil(duration/30.0)) , 0);
}
```

And the only place that FragmentCost is called is from this function below, which is *supposed* to pass different values .. but somewhere in the process, when I look at locals in FragmentCost, they're always the default values in the constructor for the class.

```
//given a skill level + duration, will return an array with the fragment usage
int* regularTotalFragCost(int skillLevel, int duration){
    int fragments[7] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    fragments[0]+= FragmentCost(skillLevel,duration, FCPs[0]);
    fragments[1]+= FragmentCost(skillLevel,duration, FCPs[0]);
    fragments[0]+= FragmentCost(skillLevel,duration, FCPs[1]);
    fragments[2]+= FragmentCost(skillLevel,duration, FCPs[1]);
    fragments[0]+= FragmentCost(skillLevel,duration, FCPs[2]);
    fragments[3]+= FragmentCost(skillLevel,duration, FCPs[2]);
    fragments[0]+= FragmentCost(skillLevel,duration, FCPs[3]);
    fragments[4]+= FragmentCost(skillLevel,duration, FCPs[3]);
    fragments[0]+= FragmentCost(skillLevel,duration, FCPs[4]);
    fragments[5]+= FragmentCost(skillLevel,duration, FCPs[4]);
    fragments[0]+= FragmentCost(skillLevel,duration, FCPs[5]);  
    fragments[6]+= FragmentCost(skillLevel,duration, FCPs[5]);
    return fragments;
}
```

For some reason I feel that I'm making a really stupid mistake somewhere, but for the life of me I can't seem to figure it out. I would appreciate any help and/or advice anyone could offer.

EDIT: Here's what the values for `fragments[]` in `regularTotalFragCost` are *supposed* to be if everything is working correctly, using a couple test values (`skillLevel = 250` and `duration = 30`)

```
FCPs[0] : Fragments: 13, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
FCPs[1] : Fragments: 17, 15, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
FCPs[2] : Fragments: 20, 14, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
FCPs[3] : Fragments: 29, 14, 9, 5, 1, 0, 0, 
FCPs[4] : Fragments: 32, 13, 10, 7, 2, 0, 0, 
FCPs[5] : Fragments: 32, 13, 10, 7, 2, 0, 0,
```

And here is what they are as of right now:

```
FCPs[0] : Fragments: 78, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
FCPs[1] : Fragments: 78, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
FCPs[2] : Fragments: 78, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
FCPs[3] : Fragments: 78, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
FCPs[4] : Fragments: 78, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
FCPs[5] : Fragments: 78, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13,
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the values stored in the vector to see if that is the case? Have you provided a copy constructor that you did not copy in the question and sets the values to those constants?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vector<FragmentCostParameters> FCPs(6);
```

creates a vector of 6 default-constructed values, numbered 0-5.

```
FCPs.push_back(FragmentCostParameters(.05, 0));
```

adds value at index 6

Comment: Ah, that's what I was looking for. Thank you Ben, looks like I learned something new about vector behavior.

Answer (score 3):

`int fragments[7]` is a local variable on the stack. Once that function returns, that memory is no longer valid. You are returning a pointer to that local variable and any access to that memory is undefined behavior.

Instead, return an `std::array`:

```
std::array<int, 7> fragments = {}; // value initialize

return fragments;
```

Comment: In addition to this, you almost certainly would receive some sort of compiler warning about this. Don't get in the habit of ignoring warnings or you're going to see this sort of undefined behavior a lot.

Comment: VS 2011 is telling me that "std" has no member "array" .. @ChrisHayes, I did receive a compiler warning about this but it seems to be working fine in the other places I've done the same behavior (returned an array) and I haven't had any problems in that scenario ..

Comment: @Holyhades666: Returning a pointer to a local variable is really evil because it does sometimes work. But only if the compiler chooses not to overwrite those stack slots. Which depends on optimization level, how many local variables it has, what functions are called in what order, and how many arguments the function uses.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: How big is your vector after you push_back your FCPs?